# How to Insert multiple rows as one row to another table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as Table A and Table B.Table A contains few records with same emp_id and date as shown in below.but time column has different values.Now i wants to insert these two records as one record to the Table B.expected output of Table B is shown Below.

Table A

[image]

Table B [expected output]

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Strawberry there can be two different times for a user for a day.if there was no two different times it should store as NULL value in Table B.

Comment: why not just group them? And also whats happening to the id?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Cant group because i want two values in time field

Comment: @colombo but your expected ouput is only 1 row

Comment: @RyanGadsdon but it contains two values

Comment: @colombo i dont really understand what you want to do. You would need to aggregate two rows if you want them to appear as 1

Comment: @RyanGadsdon yes i to appear them as 1

Comment: @colombo so you would need to group

Comment: @RyanGadsdon yes

Answer (score 0):

This would be the sort of logic that you need to display that result. Not sure it will work exactly without testing it with your particular tables etc. This will also select the data and display it like that but won't insert it (don't know why you would need that)

```
 SELECT 
 id,
 emp_id
 date,
 MAX(case when row = 1 then time end) in1,
 MAX(case when row = 2 then time end) in2
 FROM
 (
 SELECT id, emp_id, date, time
 row_number() over(partition by id) row
 FROM TableA
 ) a
 GROUP BY date;
```